# Converting a badly stringfied json to a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have some data i am pulling from a web service. This is the string

> (Body:'3886' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null,
>   messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null,
>   clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null,
>   correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null,
>   contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object,
>   contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null,
>   receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0,
>   redelivered=false, receivedExchange=,
>   receivedRoutingKey=bottomlesspit, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=62,
>   messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-sCwfLaMEqWp2GkFwFrY1yg,
>   consumerQueue=bottomlesspit])

It looks like json but the key value pairs are almost fine but the most important key which is `Body` isn't like other keys as the string would tell.

I need to read the value of `Body` and be able to get the value like this

```
   console.log(d.body);
   //This above outputs the string as shown
   obj = eval('{' + d.body + '}');
   console.log(obj);
   var match = "Body";
   var val = obj.find( function(item) { return item.key == match } );
   console.log(val);
```

How can i read the value of the key `Body`?.

Comment: For just `Body`, would be much easier (and safer) to use a regular expression instead

Comment: This is neither JSON nor valid javascript, you can't eval it. You need to implement a parser or old good regex as suggested above.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will just have to regex it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression instead of a match `Body`:

```
\bBody:'(\d*)'
```

This will catch the Body number in group 1.

Comment: I have this `var str = d.body
   var res = str.match(\bBody:'(\d*)');` where str is the string but gives a syntax error

Comment: @Gandalf is the ' seen as special caracter or changing the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a parser function get string and extract values. A very simple function is here. You can modify it also for all exceptions exist.

```js
var str = `(Body:'3886' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=bottomlesspit, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=62, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-sCwfLaMEqWp2GkFwFrY1yg, consumerQueue=bottomlesspit])`;

function f(inp) {
  var index = str.indexOf(inp),
       endIndex;
  for(var i = index; i < str.length; i ++) {
    if(str[i] == ',') {
      endIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  var output = str.substr(index, endIndex).split('=');
  return output;
}

console.log(f('consumerQueue'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regex to match and extract the Body.

Example:

```
const match = d.body.match(/Body:\'(.+)\'/)
if (match) {
  const body = match[1] // This is the value of Body
} else {
   // Unable to find Body, handle it here
}
```